# Angular 2 and TypeScript - nested components for large form

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a large form (50+ fields) which is displayed on the page using bootstrap tabs. Each tab  contains fields which are pre-populated by data pulled from JSON using HTTP. In total I have 5 tabs pulling from 5 JSON endpoints.

My component and it's template is getting big, I'd like to split each tab into it's own component. So I'd have a parent component with 5 sub/nested components (one for each tab).

After reading about how nested components work, I'm not sure if this is the best solution after all. Passing data from the child component back to the parent is done using an event emitter. All the examples I've found use (click), this is not really appropriate for my needs. I don't really want template events passing the data around (especially using a click event).

Do you know of a better event (other than click) to use, or a better solution for breaking up large forms in Angular 2 with TypeScript?

Comment: You can use a shared service where all part components "connect" to the same shared service instance and update their own state from this service and update the service when their own state changes. This way there is no passing around with events except between the components and one shared service instance.

Comment: I have a service in place already - which is working fine. But I was hoping I could break up the component as it's getting very big.

Comment: What are you worried about when you talk about "bit" - code maintenance, performance, ...?

Comment: I want to have clean code. I have various parts of my code split out into different files (pipes, models, html, etc..) - it seems a waste when most of the code is sitting inside a huge component (30+ methods inside).

Comment: If you already have services than I don't know what the problem is. If you bind your inputs to the service like `<input [(ngModel)]="sharedService.firstname">` then you should have what you want.

Comment: My service handles HTTP requests only, all the business logic is contained inside the component. I feel the component is too big and needs split out into multiple files/components. Maybe this is the wrong approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113988/discussion-between-i-like-foo-and-gunter-zochbauer).